# Persistent storage in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, local-storage

I have literally spent the last 6 hours trying to persist data using phonegap, my first approach was using the localStorate API but that was killed everytime the app restarted so it was useless. Now I implemented it by writing a file to the the filesystem, but with the following problems:

- The file is created ok
- The file has the corrent content doing

  ```
  adb pull /data/data/[package name]/friends.txt)
  ```

  I can see the content of the file
- But trying to read from it I always get NULL.

This is my code if anyone can help me... I am out of ideas now :(

`var friends = [];`

```
// Initialize the Facebook SDK
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
  FB.init({
      appId: '[myAppID]',
      nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
      useCachedDialogs: false
  });

  // Check if we already fetched our friends
  readSavedContent();

});

 function readSavedContent() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSystemForRead, fail);
 }

 function gotFileSystemForRead(fileSystem) {
     fileSystem.root.getFile("friends.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntryForRead, fail);
 }

 function gotFileSystemForWrite(fileSystem) {
     fileSystem.root.getFile("friends.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntryForWrite, fail);
 }

  function gotFileEntryForRead(fileEntry) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
              alert("Data stored is " + evt.target.result);
          };
          reader.readAsText(fileEntry);
  }

 function gotFileEntryForWrite(fileEntry) {
     fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
 }

 function gotFileWriter(writer) {
     writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        // show a message
        alert(friends.length + " friends fetched, you should be able to see them if you restart the app");
     };
     writer.write(JSON.stringify(friends));
 }

 function fail(error) {
     console.log(error.code);
     alert(error);
 }

 function login() {
     FB.login(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

         if (response.status === "connected") {
             alert("logged in: fetching friends now");

             // Fetch my friends
             FB.api("/fql?q=" + encodeURIComponent('SELECT uid, first_name, last_name, email, pic, pic_big, is_app_user, devices FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1= me()) ORDER BY first_name LIMIT 2000'),
                 function(response) {
                     friends = response.data;
                     // Store the data to the disk                  
                     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFileSystemForWrite, fail);
                 }
             );

         } else {
             alert('not logged in');
         }
     }, {
         scope: "email"
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you have forgotten one step during the file read operation.

In your case you have this order:

```
 function gotFileSystemForRead(fileSystem) {
     fileSystem.root.getFile("friends.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntryForRead, fail);
 }

 function gotFileEntryForRead(fileEntry) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
         alert("Data stored is " + evt.target.result);
     };
     reader.readAsText(fileEntry);
 }
```

When it should look like this:

```
function gotFileSystemForRead(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("friends.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFileEntryForRead, fail);
}

function gotFileEntryForRead(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        alert("Data stored is " + evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

To find out more take a look at this official Phonegape [**FileReader**](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileReader) documentation.

Then again you can always abandon this solution and use a **[persistance js](https://github.com/zefhemel/persistencejs)** for data storage. It will provide you 4+1 different options for file/data storage and it works on numerous platforms.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that :/

Answer (score 2):

As a side note, localstorage persistence was bugged in cordova(phonegap) version 2.6, so if this is your case, try migrating to cordova 2.7 recently released or downgrade to 2.5 to get rid of said bug.

Comment: Wish I could mark both your answers as correct :) thanks, that would have solved my problem with my previous approach for sure.